# How to fix pandas column header?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I want to use csv data by pandas. But there is a problem.
It is that data header shift right three columns.
Therefore, correct data cannot be used.

I think this is probably because the last three headers are empty.
Please tell me how to get correct csv data by pandas.
I poseted csv data to image description.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_df = pd.read_csv(file_path,header=0)

print(csv_df)
```

```
                      frame  Nose_x  ...  l_hand_cog_y  
0.0   NaN    NaN     0.0000  0.3287  ...        0.7593            
      0.2361 0.3696  0.7469  0.2454  ...        0.5676            
1.0   NaN    NaN     0.0000  0.2639  ...        0.7362            
      0.2454 0.3641  0.5987  0.2639  ...        0.4696            
2.0   NaN    NaN     0.0000  0.2546  ...        0.6988            
...                     ...     ...  ...           ...               
858.0 0.6574 0.5543  0.8371  0.7083  ...        0.7895            
      0.3657 0.4022  0.8528  0.2407  ...        0.7086            
859.0 0.0509 0.3587  0.8315  0.0556  ...        0.4831            
      0.6435 0.5815  0.7562  0.6944  ...        0.8002            
      0.3611 0.4022  0.8422  0.2361  ...        0.7143            

[2728 rows x 97 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include a column-name for every column in your csv-file.

```
import pandas as pd    
csv_df = pd.read_csv(file_path)    
print(csv_df)
```

Or completely delete all column names and do:

```
import pandas as pd    
csv_df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)    
print(csv_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't solve this code.

But I use it this and fix it.

```
import pandas as pd
csv_df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/data/data_estimated/box1Analize.csv',header=1,
        names= ['frame', 'Nose_x', 'Nose_y', 'Nose_score', 'Neck_x', 'Neck_y',
       'Neck_score', 'RShoulder_x', 'RShoulder_y', 'RShoulder_score',
       'RElbow_x', 'RElbow_y', 'RElbow_score', 'RWrist_x', 'RWrist_y',
       'RWrist_score', 'LShoulder_x', 'LShoulder_y', 'LShoulder_score',
       'LElbow_x', 'LElbow_y', 'LElbow_score', 'LWrist_x', 'LWrist_y',
       'LWrist_score', 'RHip_x', 'RHip_y', 'RHip_score', 'RKnee_x', 'RKnee_y',
       'RKnee_score', 'RAnkle_x', 'RAnkle_y', 'RAnkle_score', 'LHip_x',
       'LHip_y', 'LHip_score', 'LKnee_x', 'LKnee_y', 'LKnee_score', 'LAnkle_x',
       'LAnkle_y', 'LAnkle_score', 'REye_x', 'REye_y', 'REye_score', 'LEye_x',
       'LEye_y', 'LEye_score', 'REar_x', 'REar_y', 'REar_score', 'LEar_x',
       'LEar_y', 'LEar_score', 'head_cog_x', 'head_cog_y', 'head_cog_score',
       'torso_cog_x', 'torso_cog_y', 'torso_cog_score', 'r_thigh_cog_x',
       'r_thigh_cog_y', 'r_thigh_cog_score', 'l_thigh_cog_x', 'l_thigh_cog_y',
       'l_thigh_cog_score', 'r_leg_cog_x', 'r_leg_cog_y', 'r_leg_cog_score',
       'l_leg_cog_x', 'l_leg_cog_y', 'l_leg_cog_score', 'r_foot_cog_x',
       'r_foot_cog_y', 'r_foot_cog_score', 'l_foot_cog_x', 'l_foot_cog_y',
       'l_foot_cog_score', 'r_arm_cog_x', 'r_arm_cog_y', 'r_arm_cog_score',
       'l_arm_cog_x', 'l_arm_cog_y', 'l_arm_cog_score', 'r_forearm_cog_x',
       'r_forearm_cog_y', 'r_forearm_cog_score', 'l_forearm_cog_x',
       'l_forearm_cog_y', 'l_forearm_cog_score', 'r_hand_cog_x',
       'r_hand_cog_y', 'r_hand_cog_score', 'l_hand_cog_x', 'l_hand_cog_y',
       'l_hand_cog_score','undif_1','undif_2','undif_3'])

print(csv_df)
```